# R: Trying to create a basketball half court Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to merge a basketball half court with shot result data, however it shows
`"Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot"`

Can someone help me out see what's wrong with my code?
`P_half_180` stands for the graph that I created for the half court, the scatter graph works fine without `P_half_180`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

deter_chart <- nba_2015 %>%
  filter(defender_id == "253975")

P_half_180 %>%
  + ggplot(data=deter_chart,
           aes(x=touch_start_x, y=touch_start_y)) %>%
  + geom_point(aes(colour=led_to_shot))
```

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible code example? For once, I figure you are missing a `library(dplyr)` (based on your use of the pipe (`%>%`) and `filter`), but also keep in mind, that nobpdy trying to help you has your `nba_2015` object? Have look [here](https://www.jaredknowles.com/journal/2013/5/27/writing-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-in-r) for more help.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. The codes are pretty long so I only post the last part, I did load the dplyr. P_half_180 is for creating the basketball half court, geom_point shows the x-y coordinates colored by the led_ to_shot results.I am trying to show the result on the half court.

Comment: Try to put some dummy data *of the same structure*, maybe using `dput` (see the link in my previous comment). Try to cut-down the long code to a minimum needed to show your problem. If you want other people to help, they need to be able to reproduce what your did by copying your code.

Answer (score 1):

I *guess* what you want is

```r
P_half_180 %>%
+ geom_point(data=deter_chart, 
             aes(x=touch_start_x,
                 y=touch_start_y,
                 colour=led_to_shot))
```

But without knowing more about `nba_2015` and `P_half_180` I can only guess.

Comment: Thanks for the help, P_half_180 is the plot of basketball half court, nba_2015 contains the data of x-y coordinates and led_to_shot results. I am trying to show the result on the half court.I try the code and it looks like this

Comment: @AlbertTSAI: can you maybe add the output of `str(nba_2015)` and the `ggplot` command used to create `P_half_180`? I did understand *conceptially* what you try to do but there are many ways to do so and without knowing what you did, I won't be able to help. Also, your link just points to some photo printing service, nothing related to this problem.

Comment: Hi comment has word limit so I upload it to google doc https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gwkwef3Sx-1NoWK0956w2YtgULZcSc3CPc5ZVcBS_hM/edit?usp=sharing https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZPA512eSYa9gh5Ro0ShQCL-6uFMmhN8iiRM461S9ZLk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AlbertTSAI: What about the `ggplot` command that created `P_half_180`? I won't be able to help more without being able to *try it out myself* and reproducing your error. Then I can figure out how to fix it and *only then* I can explain to you what went wrong and how my fix helps. ;)

Comment: thank you :) I add the links on previous comment but didn't show, here it is https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZPA512eSYa9gh5Ro0ShQCL-6uFMmhN8iiRM461S9ZLk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AlberTSAI: It would be very helpful, if you'd *edit your question* to include  the information necessary to further help you. I went trhough all the code you supplied in your last google document, but it only defines  `cercle_3pts_in`, `cercle_3pts_out`, `cercle_ce`, `cercle_lf_in`, `cercle_lf_out`, `cercle_mil_in`, `cercle_mil_out`, `cercle_mil_petit_in`, `cercle_mil_petit_out`, `cercle_np_in`, `cercle_np_out`, `circle_fun`, `court`, `group`, `new_coords` and `rev_y`. So I still cannot reproduce `P_half_180`. Notably, there is no `ggplot` call, which I specifically asked for.